# How can I capitalize first word of "lorem" template tag output in Django 2.2?

Tags: django, django-templates

Django provides a useful "lorem" template tag that will output some "lorem ipsum" text, but the text is all lowercase. How can the first word be capitalized, to get "Lorem ipsum ... "? I know that if I had a string I could run it through a filter, but I don't know how to filter the output of a tag.

UPDATE:

I thought I had found the answer:

```
<p>
{% filter capfirst %}
{% lorem 10 w random %}
{% endfilter %}
</p>
```

But it doesn't work (even though I restart the dev server). If I change the filter to "title", that works, making every word start with a capital letter ("Lorem Ipsum Set Delor..."). Why doesn't `capfirst` work in the `filter` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, have found the solution:

`{% filter capfirst %}{% lorem 10 w random %}{% endfilter %}`

There must be no whitespace separating the `filter` tag and the `lorem` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ value|capfirst }}
```

If value is "django", the output will be "Django".

Comment: I was aware of this, but that's filtering a value, not the output of a tag. Anyhow, have found the solution.